Upload files from Nextjs to Django backend using api route
I'm using Django (DRF) in the backend and Next.js 14 in the frontend. I can upload small files without any issue, but when the file size exceeds around 100kb, the API request gets stuck in "pending" status.
Here's how the form looks in page.js:
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (avatar) formData.set("avatar", avatar);
    formData.set("bio", bio);

    const res = await fetch(`/api/auth/profile/`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    const updatedProfile = await res.json();
  };

And here's how the api/route.js file looks:
export async function POST(request, res) {
  const access = await getAccessTokenServer();
  if (!access)
    return NextResponse.json(
      { detail: "Kullanıcı girişi bulunamadı" },
      { status: 401 }
    );

  const formData = await request.formData();

  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.API_URL}/api/users/me/profile_update/`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access}` },
      body: formData,
    }
  );

When I directly send the request to Django backend from page.js file, there's no problem with uploading large files. However, when I send the request to the api/route address and then to Django, the file doesn't reach Django.
I tried to set config for api route like this.
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '10mb',
    },
  },
  // Specifies the maximum allowed duration for this function to execute (in seconds)
  maxDuration: 5,
}

